# Merge two objects in different arrays

Tags: javascript

I want to merge the objects that are in the same index on two different arrays of objects.
Which is the most simple and easy-to-understand way to go about this?

Here is the first array

```js
const countries = [
    {
        "name": "Sweden",
        "nativeName": "Sverige"
    },
    {
        "name": "Norway",
        "nativeName": "Norge"
    },
    {
        "name": "Iceland",
        "nativeName": "Ísland"
    }
]
```

Here is the second array

```java
const countryCodes = [
    {
        "country_id": "SE",
    },
    {
        "country_id": "NO",
    },
    {
        "country_id": "IS",
    }
]
```

I want to end up with this.

```java
const countriesAndCodes = [
    {
        "name": "Sweden",
        "country_id": "SE",
        "nativeName": "Sverige"
    },
    {
        "name": "Norway",
        "country_id": "NO",
        "nativeName": "Norge"
    },
    {
        "name": "Iceland",
        "country_id": "IS",
        "nativeName": "Ísland"
    }
]
```

Comment: read about `Array.map()`

Comment: and read about `Object.assign()`, and then try `a.map( (e,i) => Object.assign(e,b[i]) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```js
countries
  .map((country, i) => {
    const countryCode = countryCodes[i];
    const mergedCountry = ...; // Whatever technique to merge the two objects
    return mergedCountry;
  })
```

*Though, I would probably look to use a `zip` function on a library like Lodash*